# WaitForSeconds() is running later than expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Deneme());
}

// Update is called once per frame
IEnumerator Deneme()
{
    Debug.Log("1");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    Debug.Log("2");
}
```

It prints "2" in 4 seconds even though I put a 3 second delay. No matter how many seconds I put in, it gives 1 second more delayed output every time.

Is the problem with my computer or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe the Game lags at start? You should try to trigger the call of `StartCoroutine(Deneme());` using a KeyPress. Then start your Game and wait a few seconds before pressing the Key.

Comment: Take into account that printing things aout might take a while. The console sometimes take a while to refresh. you can log the [Time.realtimeSinceStartup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html) or a timer of your choice to check if the time according execution is correct. A second sounds a little bit too much though

Comment: When I loop the code, there is only a delay on the first output. There may be lag when starting the game.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly `c#` ...